# boto3: how to check that AWS-RunPatchBaseline is configured to install not scan?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to write a script that will ensure that all of our AWS accounts and regions are consistently configured for use with Systems Manager. We mandate that there is a maintenance window that runs weekly to perform AWS-RunPatchBaseline to scan for missing updates.

I also want to warn if there isn't a scheduled maintenance window configured to install the patches but I'm having trouble identifying when a maintenance window has been so created.

For example, if I use boto3 to describe the maintenance window tasks on the scanning maintenance window, I get this:

```
u'Tasks': [{u'MaxConcurrency': u'100%',
            u'MaxErrors': u'1',
            u'Name': u'ScanForMissingUpdates',
            u'Priority': 1,
            u'ServiceRoleArn': u'arn:aws:iam::aaaaaaaaaaaa:role/AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole',
            u'Targets': [{u'Key': u'WindowTargetIds',
                          u'Values': [u'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa']}],
            u'TaskArn': u'AWS-RunPatchBaseline',
            u'TaskParameters': {},
            u'Type': u'RUN_COMMAND',
            u'WindowId': u'mw-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
            u'WindowTaskId': u'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'}]}
```

and if I do the same for a maintenance window that has been configured to install missing updates ...

```
u'Tasks': [{u'MaxConcurrency': u'100%',
            u'MaxErrors': u'1',
            u'Name': u'InstallPatches',
            u'Priority': 1,
            u'ServiceRoleArn': u'arn:aws:iam::aaaaaaaaaaaa:role/AmazonSSMMaintenanceWindowRole',
            u'Targets': [{u'Key': u'WindowTargetIds',
                          u'Values': [u'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa']}],
            u'TaskArn': u'AWS-RunPatchBaseline',
            u'TaskParameters': {},
            u'Type': u'RUN_COMMAND',
            u'WindowId': u'mw-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
            u'WindowTaskId': u'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'}]}
```

The only identifiable difference is the task name which isn't really ideal since it means I can't absolutely verify that the task itself is correctly configured. I was expecting something to show up in TaskParameters ...

So, any ideas on how to tell whether AWS-RunPatchBaseline is configured to run as SCAN or INSTALL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this ... if you call get_maintenance_window_task for a specific maintenance window and maintenance window task, you get the TaskInvocationParameters, which is the missing information I was looking for :)

```
u'TaskInvocationParameters': {u'RunCommand': {u'Comment': u'',
                              u'Parameters': {u'Operation': [u'Scan'],
                              u'SnapshotId': [u'']},
                              u'TimeoutSeconds': 600}},
```